# How to convert a Type object to string and vice versa in Android [Kotlin]

Tags: android, kotlin, object, type-conversion, data-class

I am trying to convert a custom Data class object to a String and vice versa. How can I achieve this?

I read about Serialization and Parcelable but I am not sure how to implement it. I watched some tutorials but still can't really figure it out.

Is there any other way to achieve it? Like can I do it programmatically?

**Here is the Table where I need the conversion** :

```
@Entity(tableName = "floor_profile")
class FloorProfileEntity(

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Int? = 0,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "profile_name")
    val profileName: String? = null,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "chosen_floors")
    @field:TypeConverters(FloorsConverter::class)
    val chosen_floors: List<String>? = null,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "start_time")
    @field:TypeConverters(FloorsConverter::class)
    val startEndRunningTime: List<TimeEntity>? = null
)
```

**Time Entity Table**

```
@Entity(tableName = "add_time")
data class TimeEntity(

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int? = null,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "start_time")
    var startTime: String = "",

    @ColumnInfo(name = "end_time")
    var endTime: String = "",

    @ColumnInfo(name = "running_time")
    var runningTime: String = ""

)
```

**Converter Class**

```
    /** Converting List of TimeEntity to String and vice versa */
    @TypeConverter
    fun listOfTimeEntityToString(value: List<TimeEntity>): String {
        return value.toString()
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun stringToTimeEntity(value: String): List<TimeEntity> {
        return 
    }
```

Comment: Why do you need a Converter for Entity . TimeEntity represents the table itself ..

Comment: @ADM sorry just updated the question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61963144/how-to-make-a-typeconverter-in-room-from-a-custom-list

Comment: Use GSON or Jackson and then the time will be saved as a string, which means the ROOM annotations you are using wont work.

Comment: @cutiko I am not looking to save time. I already have saved time in the database class called as TimeEntity. Now in an another table I am trying to store objects of TimeEntity and as room doesn't allow to put non-primitive data to the database I am looking for a way to convert this TimeEntity to a String. So I can store it into database.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) as it provide simple toJson() and fromJson() methods to convert Java objects to JSON and vice-versa,

Let's say you have a user object `val user = User(name="Jane Doe",id=1)`
with Gson you can user

```
val convertJsonString = Gson().toJson(user)
```

The above gives a string that you can save to your DB

and to convert it back to your object use the fromJson method

```
val userObject = Gson().fromJson(convertJsonString,User::class.java)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use Gson or Jackson library and then the time will be saved as a string.

Comment: Can you explain this or provide some details like code examples or anything ?